# How to take date according to sql data not as system last write time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Here it is taking last photo edited time.But I want that it should take date time stored in my sql data base.

```
 var sorteddate2 = Directory
                    .GetFiles(path, "*.*")
                    .Select(fn => new FileInfo(fn))
                    .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime);
```

It is taking photo information according to the below stored procedure.So when someone is changing photo date ,it is changing in sql only not system time.So it is showing wrong date time.

```
SqlDataAdapter daage = new SqlDataAdapter("[usp_getimagedesc]'" + proid + "','" + pic + "','" + file + "' ", con);
```

And the stored procedure query is:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(23), uploaddate, 103) uploaddate, Description 
from UploadFiles  
where proj_uid=@PROJ_UID 
and UploadType=@UPLOAD_TYPE 
and [FileName]=@FILENAME 
order by Uploaddate
```

The photos are in server folder and photo details(like photo upload date) are stored in sql server.When someone is changing photo upload date it is changing in sql but not affecting system date time.So in website it is showing date time according to system date of last modified not according to sql data.

Comment: Whats the role of Sql here? which part need to be populated with sql data? can you be more specific

Comment: What database? You have not shown us the structure of it. You have shown a statement that gets the files from the directory that's it. Please update you question with that information

Comment: Please provide more details. What is the connection between the files in file system and the SQL database?

Comment: The photos are in server folder and photo details(like photo upload date) are stored in sql server.When someone is changing photo upload date it is changing in sql but not affecting system date time.So in website it is showing date time according to system date of last modified not according to sql data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx to set the last write time of the file whenever you alter the SQL record.